# Update $watch using require in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

as an angular newbie this is my problem

If I have two directives in HTML like this

```
<parent-dir param="par">
   <child-dir></child-dir>
</parent-dir>
```

and in JS like this (in parent)

```
app.directive('parentDir', function(){
return {
 restrict: 'E',
 scope: {
 param: '='
  }
 }
})
```

and in child

```
app.directive('childDir', function(){
return {
 restrict: 'E',
 require: '^parentDir',
 controller: function($scope, $element){
  <-- SHOULD I PUT WATCHER HERE -->
  },
 link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentdirCtrl){
  <-- SHOULD I PUT WATCHER HERE -->
  }
 }
})
```

where in the child directive should I make an optional $watch in order to catch all changes to the param model?

Off course if I use $watch in the parent controller, all changes in the param are reflected in the parent directive but I can`t seem to find a way to pass this information to child directive.

Comment: You don't need `$watch` since you do have a two-way binding. Also, directives inherit from their parent scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place it inside the link function which have access of the parent controller using 4th parameter of link function `parentdirCtrl`. Actually you don't need to worry about the `params` variable because it uses `=` two way binding inside directive that does update the value in both parent controller `scope` & directive `scope`. Additionally you need define controller in your `parentDir` directive so that the scope of `parentDir` directive shared with the `childDir`.

**Code**

```
app.directive('childDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^parentDir',
    template: '<div class="test">INner {{param}}</div>',
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentdirCtrl) {
      scope.$watch('param', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log(newVal);
      }) //true only if its object.
    }
  }
})
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/CGanqwrXu4QiM1KhwEU9?p=preview)

Comment: Can you also access the variable in the child directive when you do the two way binding in the parent directive. Let's say you have a controller above the parent directive would that not bind with the parent scope instead of the child scope. I think you should always define the type of binding in the child directive. Am i right here? Just trying to learn here.

Comment: @pankajparkar ... This solution seemed most reasonable to me but unfortunately I couldn't make it work like this. I can attach $watch to a parent controller and I clearly catch changes, while they can't be reflected in the child`s link function.

Comment: @IanStuart do look at answer..I think that is what you want...Thanks :)

Comment: @pankajparkar Thanks a lot this was the problem. :)